# How to get list of current AJAX Calls in the WebPage and how to track programatically, if there are finished

Tags: java, testing, selenium, webdriver

I have an interesting testing issue.
My requirement is to do performance test on a web site.

Issue here to get the REAL time taking to load the web page (i am testing). The word REAL time i refer here as the total time taken to finished all the (initial) AJAX calls (with some response). I thought of using Page Load Event.
But this approach does not give the REAL time.
Any suggestions how to do it any reference to the information is also great!

My environment: Java and WedDriver.

Comment: Selenium is not a performance testing framework.

Comment: I know that it does provide utilities for performance testing. I want to know how much time it is talking to finish the AJAX calls when the page loads. Please let me know, if there exist any approach which could help me get the  total time.

Comment: Are you aware of Speedtracer - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/speedtracer/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Tag your request objects with a timestamp and subtract this from the systime when the corresponding response is received.

Depending on your methodology you could have generic Request/Response object with a `<T>` payload and a demuxer on the server side. These generic objects could then contain code to automagically register the time when sent and received and provide the time spent to the client. Aggregating time spent for an entire page to load is a bit trickier with this approach, but not near impossible I should think - the RPC proxy might keep track of that if requests are also tagged with the originating page.

if you were to provide some concrete example of your setup/code I might be able to be more precise.

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

As everyone said, WebDriver is not meant for Performance. However, see the following method that I use sometimes.

Following code will work if you can capture the performance against some particular webelement, can be a `div` or a `span` block.

**1** Use any stopwatch. I am using apache stopwatch.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang3.time.StopWatch;
```

**2** Initialize the variable

```
StopWatch timer = new StopWatch();
```

**3** Start the timer and in next line navigate to your page. I prefer `driver.navigate().to()` than `driver.get()` as I feel it reduces other processing time to invoke a fresh URL.

```
timer.start();
driver.navigate().to(URL);
```

**4** Wait for a particular element that can specify *page loading finished*. Once it appear, in next line stop the timer.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions. presenceOfElementLocated(By.className("demoClass")));
timer.stop();
System.out.println("timer.getTime() + " milliseconds");
```

**Additional Note:** If you want to know the loading time of Network calls of any particular webapge load, use webkit like `phantomJS` or thing like `browsermobproxy`. It will return network calls in HAR/JSON file. Parse those files and you may get your time.

Hope this helps.